# python - switch case for functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

just started to mess with python and I'm looking for an alternative for `Switch-Case` like i had in `C#`

I have a Menu with 3 options for example. this is the switcher i have right now:

```
def mySC(i):
    switcher = {
        '1': funcName1,
        '2': funcName2,
        '3': funcName3
    }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda: 'Invalid')
    return func()
```

it works and I'm able to enter the function i want.
my problem is what if i want to send different arguments to each function?
for ex. if someone entered `1` i want it to enter `funcName1()` but also send a var into it like `funcName1(nums)` and for `2` i want to send `funcName1(myTwoDimList)`

how will i be able to do that?

thanks in advance, Amit.

Comment: Could you use `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: Where do your values (the one you want to pass to your functions) come from ?

Answer (score 1):

You also can add `*args` (positional) and `**kwargs` (keyword) arguments to your function:

```
def mySC(i, *args, **kwargs):
    switcher = {
        '1': funcName1,
        '2': funcName2,
        '3': funcName3
    }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda *args, **kwargs: 'Invalid')
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables you want to pass to your functions are already defined at that point, you can just use [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Python has a `partial` object in it's stdlib, but a mere `lambda` is enough here:

```
foo = 42
bar = ["s", "p", "a", "m"]
baaz = {"parrot": "dead"}  

def mySC(i):
    switcher = {
        '1': lambda: func1(foo),
        '2': lambda: func2(bar),
        '3': lambda: func3(baaz)
    }
    func = switcher.get(i, lambda: 'Invalid')
    return func()
```

If those vars aren't defined when you define your `myMC` function but are still "fixed" from one call to another (in a same process), you can add a layer of indirection to create the MySC function dynamically:

```
def create_switch(foo, bar, baaz):
    def mySC(i):
        switcher = {
            '1': lambda: func1(foo),
            '2': lambda: func2(bar),
            '3': lambda: func3(baaz)
        }
        func = switcher.get(i, lambda: 'Invalid')
        return func()

    return mySC


foo = 42
bar = ["s", "p", "a", "m"]
baaz = {"parrot": "dead"}  

mySC = create_switch(foo, bar, baaz)
mySC(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simulate a switch statement using the following function definition:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c:v in c
```

Then, your code could look like this:

```
for case in switch(i):

    if case('1') : 
       return funcName1()

    if case('2'): 
       return funcName2()

    if case('3'): 
       return funcName3()
else:
    return 'Invalid'
```